# GhostScript print to network printer in silent mode

Tags: pdf, printer, ghostscript

I'm trying to print PDF from command line to network printer in silenta mode.
Unfortunately, Ghost Script opens Windows printer dialog.

I use `Windows 2008 R2 Server`.

My command is:

`gswin64c.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%MEasyCoder PC4 (203 dpi) on aino1" "pdf.pdf"`

Printer name is: `MEasyCoder PC4 (203 dpi) on aino1` and it is network printer attached to `AINO1` computer.

Printer dialog looks like:

[image: Windows printer dialog]

In printer panel it looks like: [image: Printer control panel]

What is the right command line to avoid this dialog and print silently?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to print to a network printer in silent mode using GhostScript (gswin32c.exe) is to use \\spool\ and then the full UNC path on sOutput. All parameters are case senitive. Also, be sure to include double quotes.

```
gswin32c.exe  -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\spool\\\SRV-SBS01\iR-ADVC5030_PS_BW" "C:\Windows\Temp\~Packlist.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [gsprint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm), which uses GhostScript.  You will need to [download](http://www.ghostgum.com.au/software/gsview.htm) the old version 5 built by GhostGum for print capabilities. If you use the default installation settings, `gsprint` will be located here: `C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview`

For your example:

`gsprint -printer "\\ain01\MEasyCoder PC4 (203 dpi)" -dPDFFitPage "pdf.pdf"`

Comment: I don't see `gsprint` in my Ghostscript distribution folder. Which version are you on?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to use the old version 5 from GhostGum.

Answer (score 2):

According to the
[Details of Ghostscript Output Devices, MS Windows printers](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Devices.htm#Win):

> If a Windows printer name is specified in -sOutputFile using the
>   format `"%printer%printer_name"`, for instance:
>
> ```
> gs ... -sOutputFile="%printer%Apple LaserWriter II NT"
> ```
>
> then Ghostscript attempts to open the Windows printer without
>   prompting (except, of course, if the printer is connected to FILE:).
>   Ghostscript attempts to set the Windows printer page size and
>   orientation to match that expected by Ghostscript, but doesn't always
>   succeed. It uses this algorithm: (not quoted here)

A sample command would be ([source](https://superuser.com/a/807075/8672)):

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="%printer%\\printServer\printerNameWith Spaces" testprinter.ps
```

Comment: This command worked for me perfectly well.

Comment: For me too, it only opens the window showing "printing page 1" etc. Without this window it would be even better.

Comment: Is it possible to set the job name as output file name? The job on the printer display is named as "ghostscript output", which is undesirable, when many jobs have this same name.

Comment: Is there a way to make it not spawn the dialog when the printer isn't found?  I would rather is just failed to stderror and not lock up the process.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `\\`

```
%printer%\\ainoMEasyCoder...
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? Use it where? And how?