# Print pdf with gsprint.exe error

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to print a pdf file with the following command:
`gsprint.exe doc.pdf`

It writes this error:

```
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Ghostscript is saying: "Could not open the file". Something is wrong with your path specification or with the file permissions.

Comment: I'm in a directory C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview and the command is gsprint.exe "C:\Users\xralf\Desktop\doc.pdf". When I add -printer "Microsoft Print to PDF" the result is the same.

Comment: Try to `cd` to one of your folders, then use the command `C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsprint.exe "C:\Users\xralf\Desktop\doc.pdf"`. If this fails, try to redo it in a Command Prompt (cmd) that is Run as Administrator.

Comment: @harrymc I found out that ghostview won't open arbitrary document. I need registration number. But on their web pages is written "No more registration numbers available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using the old Ghostview, which is no longer under development.

You need to use
[Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/),
which you can download from
[this page](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html).
Choose the version under "GNU Affero General Public License" that matches your
computer.

If you are looking for `gsprint`, it is not part of Ghostscript,
but is part of [GSView](https://github.com/mgieseki/gsview)
(which uses Ghostscript).

The GSView release can be downloaded from
[this page](https://github.com/mgieseki/gsview/releases).

Comment: I downloaded it there. The 64bit version for windows.

Comment: But there wasn't gsprint.exe command, so I downloaded and installed ghostview from [here](http://www.ghostgum.com.au/software/gsview.htm)

Comment: Here is a link to 6 [version](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) but it is unavailable.

Comment: This version is an antique. You may print directly from Ghostscript, or use the latest gsprint, which I added above.

Comment: I tried the version you suggested and still cannot use gsprint.exe, because of that error. The same error when I open a document in gsview64.exe [this](https://pasteboard.co/IXwUjN7.png) error

Comment: I tried it myself and had the same error. `gsview64.exe` works, but `gsprint.exe` simply does not work, so I suggest printing from Ghostscript. This command worked for me: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="%printer%printer-name" "C:\path\file.pdf"`. Modify it for your setup.

Comment: I'm adding link to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/906575/ghostscript-print-to-network-printer-in-silent-mode)