# Command line for ghostscript to suppress print dialog and write to stderr instead

Tags: command-line, printing, ghostscript

I started my solution with what was suggested here
[GhostScript print to network printer in silent mode](https://superuser.com/questions/906575/ghostscript-print-to-network-printer-in-silent-mode)

And came up with this as a command line

```
gswin32c.exe -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%\\printserver\testprinter" "C:\absolute\file\path.pdf"
```

And it works nicely, when the printer is available.  When the printer is not available (or doesn't exist), it spawns a print dialog.  This command is being run by a custom cron service and therefore gets stuck when the dialog opens on a non interactive user.

Is there a command line switch to tell it to send to STDERR instead and just fail the print job?

Alternatively, is there a way to get ghostscript to output the available devices and I could search for the device before printing?

Comment: Can you ping %printer% first?  By cron, do you mean the windows task scheduler?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas no I wrote my own task scheduler that behaves like cron but with a web interface.  I tried pinging the printer but no luck, says not found.

Comment: Try adding `-dNOPROMPT`.

Comment: @harrymc just tried, it still gave the prompt.  Is there a way for me to get a list of all devices instead?  I could script it to fail before trying to print if the device isn't in the list

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution.

Using the command `wmic printer get Name` I get a list of printer names.  Then if the required printer is in the list, I allow the ghostscript command to run, if not then I block it.  This helps lower the chance of a lockup from the printer selection dialog popping up on an non interactive user.